# What's the benefit of using unlisted buffers?

Tags: buffers

As title. Which command will make some buffers unlisted and why it is designed to do so? I guess this is related to memory management but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help unlisted-buffer`:

```
                        *unlisted-buffer*
unlisted    The buffer is not in the buffer list.  It is not used for
        normal editing, but to show a help file, remember a file name
        or marks.  The ":bdelete" command will also set this option,
        thus it doesn't completely delete the buffer.  Settings: >
            :setlocal nobuflisted
<
```

For example, lowercase marks are remembered as long as the buffer is not wiped (listed or not). Deleted buffers can contain marks via viminfo and are unlisted.

Comment: Isn't that "in the buffer list" means `listed`? So do you mean that it's possible that there are some buffers *in* the list but `unlisted`? (Sorry for commenting on my old post, am making some plugins so I need to review what I have forgotten)

Comment: @job_start my last sentence needs corrected. "…as long as the buffer is not wiped." See any of `:help active-buffer`, `:help :bdelete`, `:help :bwipeout`, `:help :ls` for what may or may not be around for buffers in various states.